# Give the permissions to modify files only for the owner in a specific directory

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, directory, users

I have 4 users: A, B, C, D and a directory : folder10;
I want to give A and B acces to folder 10, and whenever someone create a file in this folder, he will be the only one who can modify it, the other one can only read it.
Ex : A create a file, B can open it and read it but not modify it. Same thing happens if B creates the file.

I already some similar questions but it's not the same case. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to create group(s) and add users to the group. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138476 and http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue using create one group and for that group only read access and On Linux you can assign that group using the following command.

usermod -a -G group user

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a file or directory is being created then there are permissions which are assigned to it and the division done is like this:

```
OWNER:GROUP:OTHERS/WORLD
```

These permissions can be well assigned with `chmod` to modify the access criteria of the directory or file or apply extended ACLs using `setfacl`.

Now the point is whether you want B as others or in a group.

Treating B as others can easily be done by

```
chmod <permission> <directory or filename>
```

where you replace `<permission>` with the permissions you want to grant/add/remove and `<directory or filename>` with (not surprisingly) the name of the directory or file you want to grant access to.

Like if you want only a group can read the file of which B is a member then just create a group via

```
groupadd groupname
```

While adding B just make it a part of that group using

```
useradd -n -g -groupname username
```

This will create a user with `username` and that `groupname` and using

```
setfacl -m g:<groupname>:<permission> <directoryname or filename>
```

Now you can allow that group to acess read,write or execute permission according to it.

If just you want to give permission to just a user

```
setfacl -m u:<username>:<permission> <directoryname or filename>
```